# PhpStorm editor encoding issue

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, phpstorm

[image]

I just have updated my **PhpStorm** to version **2016.1** and I have a really strange issue in editor, as you can see in the screenshot, some characters are screwed up.

When I copy/paste the text it is displayed correctly (the text before the *require* is "**dojo**"), I have tried changing the file encoding but without success (the file is UTF-8)

Someone already had this problem ? It is kind of annoying. See below my file encoding.

[image]

The problem don't seem to be the font (as suggested in comments) because *italic* is rendered:

[image]

Comment: **It's not a problem with encoding .. but issue with your font.** If you look at the screen -- only italic text has such problem. Either 1) fix your font 2) or use another font 3) or do not use italic style

Comment: I am not sure about this, check my edits

Comment: It could be bold+italic applied at the same time, for example. I cannot say any better from these screenshots as it's a custom color scheme. But such problem happens very often with [Code Source Pro font, for example](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93404).

Comment: BTW -- **1)** if you select the text and copy-paste it into another editor (e.g. Notepad++ if you are on Windows) .. or even here into the actual Question -- will it copy that mangled text fine (I mean -- will it read "dojo" when pasted)? **2)** Will it work OK if you try another standard color schema -- Default or Darcula?

Comment: Ok it is indeed a **bold+italic** problem, I am using *Envy Code R* font and never had this problem (I never had b+i font). Mind making an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not a problem with encoding .. but issue with your font.** If you look at the screen -- only italic (or italic+bold) text has such problem.

How to check it:

1. If you select the text and copy-paste it into another editor (e.g. Notepad++ if you are on Windows) .. or even here into the actual Question -- will it copy that mangled text fine (I mean -- will it read "dojo" when pasted)?
2. Will it display it fine if you try another standard color schema -- e.g. "Default" or "Darcula"?

The issue can be with actual font (corrupted font files; somehow incomplete font data etc) .. or maybe even the with the way how IDE uses/renders it (e.g. font may not have separate "bold italic" style so IDE tries to mimic it and fails).

- Either fix your font (re-download and reinstall; look for newer version maybe)
- .. or use another font
- .. or do not use italic (bold+italic) style